# Flutter APP with firebase messaging - debug receives all messages but whereas release only on active app

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction.
My app in debug mode (even on a physical device, disconnected from the debugger) receives messages in foreground, background and in stopped state. The release build fails to receive background and stopped app messages.

I tried checking (in line with this nice tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0zGEbiDJcQ) the following:

- Android Manifest,
- Build Gradle,
- App Main and Firebase initialize classes,
- Re-applied `google-services.json` form firebase console,
  In addition:
- checked signing keys,
- added SHA fingerprints for both AndroidDebugKey (this one is used on firebase messaging) and  my own siging key.

Now I am stumped as to what to do.
Here is some background (since the app works well in debug mode I concentrate on the 'externalities' here):

**SigningReport (excerpt - /android ./gradlew signingReport)**

```
> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: dev
Store: c:\Key\buzzbeebeta.jks
Alias: BuzzBeeBetaKey
MD5: ...some key  #1 ...
SHA1: ...some key  #1 ...
SHA-256: ...some key  #1 ...
Valid until: poniedzia┼éek, 9 kwietnia 2040
----------
Variant: release
Config: dev
Store: c:\Key\buzzbeebeta.jks
Alias: BuzzBeeBetaKey
MD5: ...some key  #1 ...
SHA1: ...some key  #1 ...
SHA-256: ...some key  #1 ...
Valid until: poniedzia┼éek, 9 kwietnia 2040
----------
Variant: profile
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\glowa\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: ...some key  #2 ...
SHA1: ...some key  #2 ...
SHA-256: ...some key  #2 ...
Valid until: pi─ůtek, 22 sierpnia 2053
----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: dev
Store: c:\Key\buzzbeebeta.jks
Alias: BuzzBeeBetaKey
MD5: ...some key  #1 ...
SHA1: ...some key  #1 ...
SHA-256: ...some key  #1 ...
Valid until: poniedzia┼éek, 9 kwietnia 2040
----------

.....

> Task :firebase_app_installations:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\glowa\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: ...some key  #2 ...
SHA1: ...some key  #2 ...
SHA-256: ...some key  #2 ...
Valid until: pi─ůtek, 22 sierpnia 2053
----------

> Task :firebase_core:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\glowa\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: ...some key  #2 ...
SHA1: ...some key  #2 ...
SHA-256: ...some key  #2 ...
Valid until: pi─ůtek, 22 sierpnia 2053
----------

> Task :firebase_messaging:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\glowa\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: ...some key  #2 ...
SHA1: ...some key  #2 ...
SHA-256: ...some key  #2 ...
Valid until: pi─ůtek, 22 sierpnia 2053
----------

> Task :flutter_local_notifications:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\glowa\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: ...some key  #2 ...
SHA1: ...some key  #2 ...
SHA-256: ...some key  #2 ...
Valid until: pi─ůtek, 22 sierpnia 2053
----------
```

**My `android\build.gradle` looks like this**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

        getParam = { key ->
            def value = System.getenv(key) ?: project.findProperty("env.$key")
            if (value) {
                println "$key = $value"
            }
            return value
        }
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My `android\app\build.gradle` looks like this**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pl.skilltelligence.buzzbee.beta"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        dev {
            storeFile file(SIGNING_KEY_DEBUG_PATH)
            storePassword SIGNING_KEY_DEBUG_PASSWORD
            keyAlias SIGNING_KEY_DEBUG_KEY
            keyPassword SIGNING_KEY_DEBUG_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.dev
        }
        release {
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.dev
            //added based on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78625 
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package=" <XYZ> ">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
    </queries>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.sentry.session-tracking.timeout-interval-millis"
            android:value="60000" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

             <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="true" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       
        <receiver
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <service
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ForegroundService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false"/>
     
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDbtg3r_jk9pQafCQKwxwRkhaVn6Oh85Y0" />

    </application>
    <queries>
      .....
        <intent>
           ......>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

... **and finally** the packages I use in `pubspec.yaml` for the project are:

```
  firebase_core: ^2.16.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.8
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.9.1
```

Where to look for a solution? What could be wrong bearing in mind that the debug package (after starting on a real device) works fine?
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Please add this line of code on top of your background notification function pragma("vm:entry-point")
and yes your funtion needs to be top level function

Comment: YESSS! Thank you so much! 
For those who may be wondering about the wider context here is an example:

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Divit Vaghani I now know what was wrong:

I was missing the `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` in my background message handler.

Please see below. This is based on this [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive)

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```